Largest set of monomials whose span is "co-prime" to a given polynomial
Let $K$ be a number field, and let $F \in K[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ be a polynomial. For a positive integer $d \geq 3$, define $M(F;d)$ to be the largest positive integer such that there exists a set $S$ of monomials in $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, each monomial having degree at most $d$, with $|S| = M(F;d)$ such that for any element $G$ in the $K$-span of $S$, we have that $\gcd(F,G) = 1$. In particular, we require that the varieties $V_F, V_G$ defined by $F,G$ respectively to have no common component.
Is there a way to compute $M(F;d)$ for a given $F$ and $d$, where we consider $d \rightarrow \infty$? If it helps, one can consider $F$ to be "generic".

This question seems very strange to me. A generic polynomial (for $n\geq 2$) should be irreducible, hence coprime to anything that’s not a multiple of it.
